# How can I rename a category on Wikimedia Commons?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki, wikimedia-commons

Is it possible to rename a category on Wikimedia Commons (or another Wikimedia-based wiki) so that all of the pages in that category are moved to the renamed category instead of being left in the old category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not directly possible to do that. But some wikis do have bots that can assist you with moving the items from the old category to the new one.

For Commons-specific information, including how to request renaming both to run, see [Commons:Rename a category](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons%3aRename_a_category). I expect other large wikis will have similar pages.

Comment: How can I suggest that a category be renamed? I'm looking for a template that I can post on Wikipedia that will suggest a new name for the page (without actually renaming the category.) I've found a lot of categories with confusing names, such as the category "hair" (which is only concerned with humans, and should be renamed as such).

Comment: Did you read the page I linked to? If you're looking for Wikipedia specific information, see [Wikipedia:Categories for discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Categories_for_discussion).

Comment: You can also replace a category's content with `{{category redirect|New Category Name}}`, and then copy and paste the category's original content to the new article. The category's content will then be moved to the new page (by a bot).

Comment: Also, you can move all items from one category to another using the Cat-a-Lot user script.